# Conditional and interrogative 'if' in Romance languages

Tags: syntax, list-of-languages, questions, interrogatives, conditionals

In English, the prototypical word for introducing a conditional antecedent is the word *if.* This word is homophonous with the interrogative word *if* used in subordinate interrogative clauses:

> 1. **If** Bertha's arrived, she'll let us know.
> 2. I wonder **if** Bertha's arrived.

In French, Italian, Sardinian, Spanish and Catalan the corresponding word to conditional *if* is also homophonous with a closed interrogative subordinator/complementizer.

What I would like to know is:

- Are there any Romance languages in which the word for *if* is ***not*** also an interrogative  subordinator?
- If so, which languages, and what are the corresponding words?
- Lastly, if you know of other Romance languages where conditional 'if' ***is*** also an interrogative word, that information would also be useful.

Comment: Both are also _se_ in Portuguese. Wiktionary and Google Translate suggest that Romanian also uses _dacă_ for both, but I don’t speak Romanian, so I can’t confirm that. I don’t know of any Romance languages where the conditional is not also interrogative. (Though, as with English _whether_, there are Romance languages that have other words usable for only one of the two; Portuguese _caso_ is only conditional, for example.)

Comment: if subordinator and if preposition. Pullum:  https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1912

Comment: @Lambie Yes, a fateful post which changed the course of my PhD!

Comment: A while back I had a huge to-do re if in Spanish with a simple past (when si is conditional, the verb is always subjunctive.  But here, it was: Si fue a Londres, no me lo dijo. If he went to London, he didn't tell me. Where si means: on the assumption he went to London, he didn't tell me and not if conditional.

Comment: @Lambie On some accounts, that's still conditional, but it's not a remote/subjunctive/fake past/backshifted conditional. The English version there is telling, because is has no past tense modal in the main clause. Obviously it has no 'conditional' verb in the Spanish.

Comment: Right. But what I had said re the Spanish to the honcho was that in Spanish, all conditionals have to have a subjunctive except for one in the present (If I go, they will see me. Si voy, me verán. And if it was a subjunctive, it couldn't be a conditional.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, right, The problem is that we usually learn what we're teaching from other people/resources. But, especially when it comes to conditionals, they massively oversimplify the real situation!